# Can't format my HDD after cloning Windows 10 install to SSD

Tags: ssd, formatting, clone

I recently acquired an M.2 SSD to increase the speed on my Legion Y720, then I used EaseUS TODO Backup Home to clone my Windows installation from the HDD to the SSD. Everything went normal, as I'm writing this from the recently cloned installation on my SSD, but now I can't format the HDD, as Windows says that it's currently being used! Then I went on to check my Resource Manager and saw that some of the processes being executed are actually on my E:/ (that's the HDD)!. Did I do something wrong? Is there any way to fix it?

Edit: Just tested removing the HDD from my notebook, and I was able to boot and use my Windows just fine with only the SSD, but when I put back the HDD, it still won't let me format it, always saying it is in use.

Comment: Not sure why some people voted to close.  I think this is a legitimate question.  Unfortunately I don't have the Windows knowledge to advise how to fix, but the way I would do it would be to boot a version of linux, then delete the first 1k of the disk with a command like dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1024 count=1   (make sure that sdX is changed to the appropriate drive). You will then have an unpartitioned disk to repartition and format.

Comment: So, doing this would just remove the disk's MBR? Seems like a pretty simple solution. Could try this out later, but if there's a simpler solution that does not involve having to use flash drives or recovery disks, I'm open to suggestions :) But thanks anyway @davidgo

Comment: Yes, this would remove the MBR.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a little embarassing, but the I downloaded Mark Russinovich's [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and through that tool I was able to verify which process was actually messing the formatting of my HDD, and it was Google Drive Sync, which stored the synced files in my E: partition, which was my HDD's previous Windows installation partition. When I disabled Google Drive Sync, I succesfully formatted my HDD and, well, everything is all right now :)